# Macbook opens desktop instead of opening the app that I clicked in the dock

Tags: dock, desktop, ventura, application-switcher

When I have some full screen apps in the dock and I try to open one of them (by clicking at it in the Dock) my Macbook sometimes (it happens randomly) opens desktop instead of the app I need. So I have to click at this app once more in order to get to the right space. Swipes and Alt-Tab works perfectly, but I also want my Dock to work correctly. Is there any way to solve this? I am running macos Ventura 13.2

Comment: Do you have [the same question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453905/macbook-opens-default-desktop-when-i-click-on-fullscreen-app-from-dock)?

Comment: Yes, but there is no solution

Comment: Having the same problem last year on the current and previous Mac versions. No idea what is the source of this bug.